# Google Maps V3 infobox always in center

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm struggling with google maps.
Yesterday I had a problem to show an infowindow in the place that I wanted and an user of stackoverflow told me to try this:

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.5/src/infobox.js

That plugin solved me the problem, but I get another one.
I wanted to be able to resize the page and always get the marker position at the center of the map. How can I do this ?

Heres my code:

```
function initialize() {

    var loc, map, marker, infobox;

    loc = new google.maps.LatLng(40.20384, -8.39935);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
         zoom: 18,
         center: loc,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
         scrollwheel: false,
         draggable: false,


    });

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: loc,
        visible: true,
        icon: "public/images/logo.png",
    });

    infobox = new InfoBox({
         content: document.getElementById("over_map"),
         disableAutoPan: false,
         maxWidth: 150,
         pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(100, -100),
         zIndex: null,
         boxStyle: {
            background: "gray",
            opacity: 0.75,
            width: "280px"
        },
        closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px",
        isHidden: false,
        closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif",
        infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
    });

    infobox.open(map, marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infobox.open(map, this);
        map.panTo(loc);
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Hope someone could help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `window.onresize` to that :

```js
window.onresize=function() {
   map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
}
```

see this working demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/Fae26/** - try resize the frames or resize the entire window.